# How to check the status between 2 servers?

Tags: c, ruby, linux

There are 2 servers, they need to know the status(live oe dead) each other. my method is a long tcp connecting, Is there any better method? thanks.

Comment: +1 for @Yossarian's ping (are they still trying to kill you?)

Comment: but I want to check status by program

Comment: @why **Ping** is a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I`m no sysadmin, but why not simply use nmap or the likes to check if the ports your servers are listening on are still open? I mean, you simply want to know if they are alive or dead, right? When one of your server crashes, the port shouldn´t be open anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'ping'

def alive?(host)
 Ping.pingecho host, 15, 80
end
```

Ping.pingecho accepts three arguments, the hostname or ip, timeout period and a port number. You can find more info about the subject [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ping/rdoc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
system('ping -c 5' + host)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for some sort of cluster/heartbeat functionality.  If that is the case, maybe the [Linux-HA](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page) project may help (never used it myself).